# Get filepath from filelocation using Perl and Regex

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have a

```
$path = "/usr/local/bin/mybinary"
```

how can I use regular expressions to get `$regex = "/usr/local/bin"`.

I am new to regex. I tried as follows:

```
$regex =~ s/w+/.*\//
```

This doesnt work. How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a regex:

```
$path = "/usr/local/bin/mybinary"

my $parent = $path =~ m{(.*)/} ? $1 : warn "Unrecognized";
```

However, I would recommend using [`File::Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) or similar module:

```
use File::Basename;

my $dir = dirname($path);
```

Comment: This works ! Why do we use the warn "Unrecognized" after the ':'? Is it mandatory?

Comment: You should always check to make sure a regular expression actually matched before using a capture group.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code as shown below:

```
use File::Basename;

my $path = "/usr/local/bin/mybinary";
my $filename = basename($path);
my $dir = dirname($path);
```

Besides File::Basename, there's also Path::Class, which can be handy for more complex operations, particularly when dealing with directories, or cross-platform/filesystem operations. It's probably overkill in this case, but might be worth knowing about.

```
use Path::Class;

my $file = file( "/usr/local/bin/mybinary" );
my $filename = $file->basename;
```

Comment: There is also Path::Tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex.

```
$path =~ s/^(.*)\/.*/\1/
```

Group index 1 contains the string you want.

Comment: It's better to use one of the file path processing modules than a regex to process paths.